# Automatic pointer for Symbian

Tags: memory-management, symbian

Is there any kind of automatic pointer, similar to `auto_ptr` or `scoped_ptr`, for Symbian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. If you mean native Symbian C++, of course. I can only propose you to use `template <class T> class TAutoClose`, which can be used to call `Close()` method on different R-classes, when TAutoClose instance goes out of scope. For example,

```
RFile myFile;
TAutoClose<RFile> iFile;
iFile.iObj = myFile;
```

`myFile::Close()` will be called when iFile goes out of scope.

Hope this helps. Symbian development is not the easy. :)

Comment: I supposed as much, but I meant something like Boost. Of course such classes CAN be written.

Comment: Sure they can. Speaking about Boost, it is available for Symbian as a part of Open C++ plugin, but Open C++ is often not an option (at least for many of my Symbian programming tasks).